# Extracting the next line data of a file if regex pattern matches in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract the next line data of a text file if regex pattern matches in Java. I am able to detect and match the pattern data in a text file, But unable to print the next line of pattern data.

Test data:

```
*** Explorer
GenV Deno Znet
```

Regular Expression for matching the Explorer

```
[*\\+]+[\\s+]+[Explorer]+[:]
```

Kindly help me on how to get the next line if *** Explorer pattern is found.

Comment: btw I have removed `javascript` tag since you are using `java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with a capturing group for the next line after your search pattern:

```
[*]+\s+Explorer\R(.*)
```

Next line is captured in group #1

**Regex Breakup:**

- `[*]+\s+Explorer` - Match your search pattern
- `\R` - Match any newline character
- `(.*)` - Match and captured full line in group #1

In Java use:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "[*]+\\s+Explorer\\R(.*)";
final String input = "*** Explorer\nGenV Deno Znet";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("match: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JDTL46/2)

Comment: final String regex =  "[*]+\\s+Explorer\\R(.*)";
     String str = scan.findInLine(regex);
     System.out.println(str);

Comment: Don't use `scanner`. Use `Pattern, Matcher` and then `matcher.find()`

Answer (score 0):

You can Use:

```
[*\s]+Explorer\n(.*?)$
```

---

### [image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q4dWEd/3)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters the regex is not going to match "*** Explorer"

It will match "*** Explorer:"

If this is java, can't you just read the next line?

```
        while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
            hasMatch = lineText.matches(regex);
            if(hasMatch) {
                lineText = lineReader.readLine();
                System.out.println(lineText);
            }
        }
```

Works for me.